# "possible duplicate of..." autogenerated comment overescapes question title

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, automatic-comments

Example:

[Parse ISO8601 date in Objective-C (iPhone OS SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796408/)

The comment appears as:

"possible duplicate of Parsing unsupported date formats in via Cocoa&rsquo;s NSDate"

(duplicated question was [Parsing unsupported date formats in via Cocoa's NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399527/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I forgot that comments HTML Encode later in the pipeline.

I removed the call to `HtmlUtilities.EncodeFancy(title)` on that..

Comment: Hmm, reminds me of [Making Wrong Code Look Wrong](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). Maybe you should use Hungarian notation.

Comment: Backticks in titles [are rendered as code](http://i.imgur.com/jNkU9.png). Is that expected behaviour? (This only happens in auto-comments; not in auto titles for bare trilogy URLs in normal posts.)

Comment: [The same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85458/how-to-see-which-badges-im-close-to-earning) problem (?) for the auto-inserted ["Possible duplicates" fragment](http://i.imgur.com/wtNsG.png).